# When I filter in the Assets in the editor to search by type for Prefab it find 45 prefabs but in my script it find 54 what is the right one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetAllObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
       
    }

    private static string GetClickedDirFullPath()
    {
        string clickedAssetGuid = Selection.assetGUIDs[0];
        string clickedPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(clickedAssetGuid);
        string clickedPathFull = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), clickedPath);

        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(clickedPathFull);
        return attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) ? clickedPathFull : Path.GetDirectoryName(clickedPathFull);
    }

    private static string GetPath()
    {
        string path = GetClickedDirFullPath();
        int index = path.IndexOf("Assets");
        string result = path.Substring(index);

        return result;
    }

    static List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    private static void GetFolders()
    {
        paths = new List<string>();

        string selectedPath = GetPath();

        string[] assetsPaths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();

        foreach (string assetPath in assetsPaths)
        {
            if (assetPath.Contains(selectedPath))
            {
                if (assetPath.Contains("Prefabs"))
                {
                    paths.Add(assetPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    [MenuItem("Assets/Add Components")]
    public static void AddComponents()
    {
        GetFolders();
    }
}
```

When I put a brea kpoint in the end of the GetFolders method it shows on the List paths 54 prefabs.
In the editor it shows 45.

Comment: did you try to compare the results? what is the difference / which elements are in the list that are not in the search in Unity ? 54 elements is a size where this can easily be checked ;)

Comment: `what is the right one?` ... I would say the one you expect ;) If you want to get more results then probably your method .. if however you want to mirror the Unity search tool then your method seems to be not right ;)